# How to get Repeater Item data object on ItemCommand event

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a repeater of LinkButtons and on the ItemCommand event. I need to get the Data Object that created the link button.

My DataSource is List so on ItemCommand I need MyObject object = ???

Comment: I don't think you can.  You might be able to with a ListView though, instead of a Repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this? This will send the ID to the code behind using `CommandArgument` so it can be processed.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" CommandName="myCommand">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

And in code behind:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "myCommand")
    {
        string myID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
}
```

Or you can use `CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'`. Then you know the row number and can access the corresponding index in your source.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object DataItem = (Object) e.Item.DataItem;
```

And then use the `DataItem`.